# Why Google Play Vitals ANR No StackTrace?

Tags: google-play, stack-trace, android-anr-dialog, android-vitals

I found that some ANR no stack trace at Google Play Console Vitals recently.

[image: like this]

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

After 30 Aug 2021 they changed this in reports

[image: Screen from console]